# How to control modal opening/closing without an input tag in daisyui?

Tags: svelte, daisyui

I'm using daisyui in svelte, and I don't know how to use the modal programmatically without `<input>` tag or `<a>` tag, is it possible to do? I want to be able to control the open/close of the modal through javascript. What's the most elegant way to do it?

The modal component is [here](https://daisyui.com/components/modal/).

Found [this solution](https://svelte.dev/repl/b95ce66b0ef34064a34afc5c0249f313?version=3.53.1) on the web, but isn't it kind of complicated for such a simple functionality?

Also tried to use the official example without `<input>` or `<a>`, replaced with `{#if opened}`, but failed to open the modal

Comment: Please include all relevant code inside the question itself (do not just link to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the component uses a checkbox state to open/close the modal. This makes it possible to add this interactivity without any JS at all. The documentation however states that there also is the class `modal-open`:

> Add/remove this class to open/close the modal using JS

So that could be used with a local flag via `class:modal-open={opened}`.

Comment: If I want to close the modal by clicking outside, what should I do? I want to avoid using <label> and <input> tags which are introduced in doc, because the modal would be closed anyway by clicking once, sometimes I want it to stay after one click.

Comment: You can use [`<svelte:window>`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-window) to add a top level `click` event listener, then you just need to check if the event `target` is inside or outside the modal (you can bind the modal element to a variable using `bind:this`).

Comment: Actually, the modal provides its own backdrop on which a listener can be added ([Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/a9e64888b96c473eb16dac894700dc18?version=3.53.1)).  You would also want to add keyboard events for pressing escape.